# Connecting to a server-side SQL database via php with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I have been trying to look over an example to figure out how to connect to a server's SQL database from a client using JQuery, AJAX, and PHP, and though it is old it seems well done and straight forward: [Example Link](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/107).A single folder contains all of my php files as well as the product version of jQuery (javascript-1.10.2.min.js).

**Problem 3 - Fixed**

JS console shows [Object, "parsererror", SyntaxError] at

```
var id = data.data[0];              //get id, data['data'][0] works here as well
```

in client.php. Object responseText shows ..."No Database Selected"... I have updated my client.php based on Daedalus' response and am still getting the same error.

Error was in mislabeling a variable ($link instead of $con) in server-api.php

-- Code --

db-connect.php:

```
<?php 

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Example php script for fetching data from mysql database
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "password";

$databaseName = "server-db";
$tableName = "inventory";

?>
```

server-api.php:

```
<?php 

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 1) Connect to mysql database
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
include 'db-connect-99k.php';
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('zgc7009_99k_db', $con);
$array = array('mysql' => array('errno' => mysql_errno($con), 'errtxt' =>mysql_error($con)));

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 2) Query database for data
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
$array['mysql'][] = array('errno' => mysql_errno($con), 'errtxt' =>mysql_error($con));
$array['data'] = mysql_fetch_row($result);                    //fetch result

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 3) echo result as json 
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

client.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1) Create some html content that can be accessed by jquery
-------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<h2> Client example </h2>
<h3>Output: </h3>
<div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>

<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function () 
{

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'server-api.php',           //the script to call to get data          
    data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                   //for example "id=5&parent=6"
    //dataType: 'json',                //data format  (comment out or get parsererror) 

    // Successful network connection
    // Successful network connection
    success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
    {
      var id = data.data[0];              //get id, data['data'][0] works here as well
      var vname = data.data[1];           //get name
      //--------------------------------------------------------------------
      // 3) Update html content
      //--------------------------------------------------------------------
      $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); //Set output element html
      $('#error_code').html("Success!");
    },
  error: function() {
    console.log(arguments);
  }
  });
}); 

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Problem 1 - Fixed**

Thanks to user help, I have managed to get rid of my original error of:

```
OPTIONS file:///C:/Users/zgc7009/Desktop/Code/Web/php/server-api.php No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. jquery.js:8706
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/zgc7009/Desktop/Code/Web/php/server-api.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

**Problem 2 - Fixed [now running on temporary web server (see link at bottom)]**

Now I am running WAMP (including phpmyadmin and apache) as my webserver. I can run my php page with script (client.php) no problem, it runs, can't seem to find any errors in my logs. However, I still never seem to hit the success function of my script. I am assuming that I have inappropriately set something somewhere (eg localhost/"my site".php) but I am not sure where.

I also tried changing my AJAX function a bit, to include .done:

```
$.ajax({      
  url: 'localhost/server-api.php',           //the script to call to get data          
  data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                   //for example "id=5&parent=6"
  dataType: 'json',                //data format   

  // Successful network connection
  success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
  {
    var id = data[0];              //get id
    var vname = data[1];           //get name
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 3) Update html content
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); //Set output element html
  }

}).done(function() {
    $('#output').html("AJAX complete");
});
```

but my output value never gets changed within the ajax call. I could be implementing .done incorrectly, but I just can't seem to figure out why I am not hitting anything and can't seem to find a log that is a help in finding the next step.

On previous edit I removed localhost from php calls ('localhost/server-api.php' returned a 404) and now I am stuck again. I get a 304 Not Modified from my jQuery call, but I thought that, as of jQuery 1.5 ajax handled this as a success so I should still be hitting my html text update (correct?) and I don't.

WAMP access Log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2014:14:22:45 -0500] "GET /client.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2146
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2014:14:22:45 -0500] "GET /jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2014:14:22:45 -0500] "GET /server-api.php HTTP/1.1" 200 38
```

Note - this is the only log that updates when I refresh client.php in my browser. my js console stays blank. I have uploaded this to a temp site: [zgc7009.99k.org/client-99k.php](http://zgc7009.99k.org/client-99k.php)

Comment: In this case old is not good.  You really should not be learning to use `mysql_*` functions as they are deprecated.  Instead, find tutorial that uses `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: So what have you done to narrow down the problem?  Have you looked in web developer tools to see if the AJAX call is even made, or whether it gets a 200 response code (or something else) from the server?  Do you see any errors in your console log or PHP server logs?

Comment: Error doesn't trigger on a failed db connection, it triggers on network related problems.  Read the documentation instead of just assuming.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I really have done very little with web based anything so this is a bit of a grind for me. I thought I checked the appropriate console but apparently I missed something. On double-checking my web developer console there was an error with my error: function call in my client.php. After removing that, everything loads without error in the web-console, ajax is being called, but hitting with success fails. Any way you could point me in the right direction as to figuring out why it isn't successful?

Comment: Daedalus - I did read the documentation I found @ http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and thought that it fit with what I am trying to do. My comments are poorly worded, the assumption that I made is that if I connected to the network I would be able to connect to the database, apparently this isn't the case.

Comment: @zgc7009 Firstly, SO doesn't notify me if you don't use the @ + name syntax I just used at the start of this reply.  Secondly, where in the documentation does it say it detects a database connection error?  Javascript is client-side, not server-side; the only error it will detect, as described in the documentation, is if the request itself fails.. such as a server problem(500), or a page not found(404), or something else.  Network related issues, only.  It doesn't have any connection with `mysql_*`.

Comment: @zgc7009 Also, you make no attempt at checking for errors db wise; I don't know the stuff off the top of my head, so refer to the relevant php pages to echo your error number/string, and return that, then act accordingly.

Comment: @zgc7009 [Here is an example demonstrating what `error:` does](http://jsfiddle.net/u57mf/).

Comment: @zgc7009 I apologize if I'm coming off as hostile; I don't mean to be.

Comment: @Daedalus - Sorry, I thought the @ was in there. The documentation doesn't say anything about connecting to the database. My error came in making the jump in assuming that if I successfully connected to my network, it would connect to my database; or on the other end of that if I failed to connect to my network obviously I would fail to connect to my database. I didn't stop to think that just because I get through the network that I might not be connecting to my database on that network. Thank you for your example and for your responses. All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgive me if the following is drawn out, but I wish to explain all that I can;

Firstly, as noted in comments, the `error` method of the jQuery [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method only gets called if there is an error when the method attempts to load the requisite php page you(or it(if you don't specify a url, it uses the current page)) has specified.  An error in this regard would be something like a 404(page not found), 500(server error), or what-have-you.

The current error you are experiencing is two-fold:

1. You are not running a server on your computer(or you are and aren't accessing the page via the correct url in your browser(it should be `localhost/path/to/file.extension)`
2. Same origin policy is preventing your page from even being loaded

In regards to problem #1, a php page needs to be processed by your php interpreter, which you need to have installed on your system.  I would recommend something like [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) to suit this case, though there are plenty others available.

When accessing a server which is running on your machine, one uses the `localhost` url in the address bar, no protocol(`http://`,`https://`,`ftp://`,etc), and never a `file:///` protocol.  For example, if I were to visit the folder test's index.php file, it would be `localhost/test/index.php`.

In regards to problem #2, browsers have various restrictions in place in order to prevent malicious code from executing..   One of these restrictions is the [Same Origin policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy), a policy which restricts documents of a differing origin than the originating request from accepting that request.  For example..

If we have a server at `domain.website.com`, and it makes a request to `otherdomain.website.com`, the request will fail as the endpoint of the request is on a different domain.

Likewise, the same exists for any requests made in regards to a `file:///` protocol..  It is always<sup>1</sup> treated as a different origin, and it will always<sup>1</sup> fail.  This behavior can be changed, but it is not recommended, as it is a security hole.

[I also recommend you check out MDN's article on SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FSame_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Of course, to fix all this.. install a web server(like xampp or wamp) on your machine(depending on your OS) or use a hosted web server, never open your html file by double clicking it, but by visiting its url(according to your webserver's directory(it differs per server)), and always make sure your domains and ports match.

- 1: Except in certain cases, such as [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same-origin_policy_for_file%3a_URIs)

**Edit 1:**

Don't know why I didn't see this before; we could have avoided headaches.. anyway, firstly, change the error catching you do here:

```
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
echo mysql_errno($con) . ": " . mysql_error($con). "\n";
```

To:

```
$array = array('mysql' => array('errno' => mysql_errno($con), 'errtxt' =>mysql_error($con)));
```

And then, change your array set after your db handling to this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");          //query
$array['mysql'][] = array('errno' => mysql_errno($con), 'errtxt' =>mysql_error($con));
$array['data'] = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

To explain what I've changed, and why..  Your first echo was causing the json parser to fail when parsing your echoed json.  If you didn't have your console open during your refresh, you wouldn't have seen that it did in fact execute the ajax request.  You also do not define an error handler, so you would have never known.  In order to parse the new json I just created above, modify your success handler's variable declarations above into this:

```
var id = data.data[0];              //get id, data['data'][0] works here as well
var vname = data.data[1];           //get name
```

Of course, if your mysql causes any errors, you can then access those errors with the following:

```
console.log(data.mysql);
```

Again, in your success function.  To see if you have any errors with the actual `.ajax()` method or such, you can just do this for your error handler:

```
error: function() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Much thanks for all of the help, I know it can be frustrating helping someone that doesn't even really know what they are asking. I will check this out and get back to you with a response, but I am going to presume it has me in the right direction.

Comment: [Here's some other bit of good reading as well](https://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Standard_browser_security_features).

Comment: Three sentences in and already a helpful link. Big props to you for taking extra time to help

Comment: I have updated my question, I am making progress but still seem to be missing something. From what I can tell, everything is setup through WAMP appropriately (from what I can tell). Whatever I am missing, it has something to do with my AJAX call. I do have some more reading to do, just figured I would update. Thanks very much again.

Comment: @zgc7009 First thing's first; in your browser's javascript console(hit the F12 key on your keyboard), what does it say?

Comment: Every time I think I check all of my logs, another one pops up. Thank you again, I somehow managed to rename a php and forget to change things around for it, I have fixed that and then removed the localhost from my php calls that was causing a 404 on server-api.php. I am at the point again though where none of my logs seem to show me anything of concern but my js console remains blank and I never seem to step through ajax. If you don't mind dredging through a bit more I have updated my post, if not I completely understand and thank you again for getting me to this point.

Comment: Thank you for the response and sorry for the delay. I have updated my code to show my current error. Again, thank you so much. Your responses have been amazingly helpful.

Comment: @zgc7009 According to your mysql error in the first object passed to the arguments object, you didn't select a mysql database, -or-, there was some connection trouble in that regard..  but, the error says 'no database selected'.

Comment: @zgc7009 .. Sorry again; didn't see it before, you never do select a db, see [here for how to do that](http://www.php.net/mysql_select_db).

Comment: @zgc7009 In your most recent update, `$link` should be `$con`.

Comment: I am actually proud to say of everything I actually caught that ONE thing haha. Got it connected, now I just need to figure out how to return what I actually want from my database. You got me connected though, someone in the vicinity of this man please give him a hug. Thanks very much.

Comment: @zgc7009 Two notes; 1. mysql_query() returns `false` on error; 2. I messed up slightly with the mysql error object for your json; it should be: `$array = array(array('mysql' => array('errno' => mysql_errno($con), 'errtxt' =>mysql_error($con))));`  The extra array means you add to that array instead of the object itself, so its easier to pick apart and add to.  And you're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

please you should start learning to  PDO or Mysqli real fast, mysql_* will soon be depreciated, that is soonest, let me rewrite your query for you using PDO and prepared statements, you can kick it off from there.

```
$connectionStr = 'mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$databaseName.'';   
$driverOptions = array();    

     $dbh = new PDO($connectionStr, $user, $pass, $driverOptions);              
     $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);     

     $query  =  $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
     $query->execute();

     $array = fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

     echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Re-writing the query using PDO doesn't answer the OP's question.  On top of that, this doesn't use paramiterized queries, and thus is not safe from injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but I still don't understand why I am having trouble connecting to my database. Though it may be an old way of doing it, it should still work and doesn't for me.

Comment: @zgc7009 Please account for mysql connection errors, and give the requisite error you get should you get one.  You won't be able to tell if there is something wrong with your query without it.

Comment: @Daedalus As ignorant as this may make me sound, how do I check my connection log? I thought I figured out how to run error logs but I guess I am still confused. Is it done using mysqli_error()? This project is turning out to be more of a headache than I thought, didn't realize there was so much to server-client interactions.

Comment: @zgc7009 [This page should describe what you need to do to troubleshoot your db interaction](http://www.php.net/mysql_error).

Comment: @Daedalus You are seriously my hero, can't explain how much you have helped me so far. I was trying to do my error calls from the client side (still haven't grasped the whole server-client thing yet). I have updated my original post to reflect my error code.

Comment: @zgc7009 This is probably the final question: Are you running this on a webserver, or are you opening the html file by double-clicking it(eg, the file:/// protocol)?

Comment: @Daedalus I am running it directly from my laptop by double-clicking. Did I make my boldest assumption there in assuming that my laptop could run the server as well as the client side without setting up an actual server to run it through?

Comment: @zgc7009 Let me answer you in an answer.